# Representing asset expiration and rating in a single dashboard

Tags: usability, user-expectation, info-visualisation, dashboard

We're presently going through introducing a new concept into an existing customer facing dashboard. At present customers are used to navigating their assets by using a site-wide "rating". This is safety based and represented using Red/Orange/Green traffic light colours.

The new requirement is to also surface asset expiration in the same screen. There's a few different schools of thought internally on how's best to do this.

**Existing**
[image]

Our Existing UI showing simply the safety of the assets on a user account. As is quite clear the separate bins add up to the total. They provide navigation to the asset management page pre-filtered to the safety level clicked.

**Contributing to totals**
[image]
The first suggestion internally is to have an extra row supplementing our pre-existing safety categorisation showing the same safety figures, but adjusted for expiration. These new figures are *not* just the numbers of safe/warning/dangerous assets that are now expired. The new red section is an amalgamation of both Dangerous & Expired. The new orange section is an amalgamation of Warning & Expiring. The new green section being all Safe assets less those that are expired or expiring.
The further 2 new boxes representing the expiring assets without any reference to their safety rating.

**Separate Concerns**
[image]
Keep the 2 facets to an asset as separate figures and allow diving into either of them separately without any combined figures.

**Hybrid**
[image]
Display both facets to an asset as equal but separate concerns but make clear the assets that are problematic because of safety of expiration.

There is a strong internal desire to provide a "quick view" of assets that have problems. Though I'm very conscious of the fact that existing users will have a learning curve and potentially different figures than they're used to.
I've intentionally kept mine and the product team's opinions out of this post in the interest of a fair representation of all ideas.

Comment: Are expired assets (regardless of safety level) a 'danger'? Are expired assets something that need to be dealt with as soon as possible?

Comment: They're a concern in that they require action. They're not dangerous. Just non-compliant. A user is likely only to be concerned with safety OR expiration.

Answer (score 5):

## Try using a matrix that allows the user to scan by safety level or time (expiry states) in one view.

Since users are concerned with Safety OR Expiration, a matrix allows you to view either concern in a single component.

#### Treat the asset totals as a title; allow the breakdown of the total to show in the matrix itself.

Instead of putting asset totals alongside the risk levels (which is a summary value, not a risk category), perhaps you can make it part of the title of the dashboard section.

[image]

#### Display compliance (current to expired) using position on the vertical axis

Borrowing from Trello, you can get an extension which shows **[cards 'aging'](https://help.trello.com/article/820-card-aging)**, for tasks that are not dealt with. Icons with hover tips for redundancy, and saturation can emphasize transitions between current to expired.

#### Grouping and totals for risk levels

I'm not sure what's more important to show first, but you could silo the risk levels into vertical lanes in any order you decide, and have a total at the bottom (or in the category title bar).

[image]

**Update: Showing out of compliance assets; an option**

In response to your comment, perhaps you can reverse the order, and give a heavier treatment to any asset that's not current. This is by no means any particular solution, but just a small shift in graphic emphasis:

[image]

Comment: In our use case "expiry" is more severe with time. So unlike trello an expired asset is more important than an in-date one. Though we're definitely thinking about a matrix now. Thanks